# Sorting other instances by similarity in Django

Tags: python, django, sorting, similarity

I've got a simple Model like this where each record describes a make and model of car:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body_shape = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(
        ('hatch', 'Hatchback'),
        ('saloon', 'Saloon'),
        ('4x4', '4x4'),
    ))
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    doors = models.IntegerField()
    enginecc = models.IntegerField()
```

Simple stuff but here's the tricky part: This is part of a used car listing system and if a user is looking at one car, I'd like to show them the next five *most similar* cars... Where similarity is derived from being the same make *and* model, body shape, number of seats, number of doors, etc. None of these things need to be the same, they just need to be ordered in a way where they're closest to a given car.

I've actually no idea where to even start here. How do you rank things by similarity on multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

what about [predictionio](https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO)??  look at a [sample work](http://blog.prediction.io/build-discovery-feature-course-platforms-predictionio/#.UpMicFQW3Zg).

it has a [python api](https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-Python-SDK) too .

It has also a neat [Python documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PredictionIO/) using sphinx

#### Update

what about django filter method

```
from django.db.models import Q
Car.objects.filter(Q(make__startswith=curcar.make), 
    Q(model__icontains=curcar.model) | Q(seats=curcar.seats)....etc)
```

Comment: The idea of farming this out to an external engine seems extravagant. I was hoping I could keep this within the database level, perhaps with a few dabs of Python here and there to pull it together.

Comment: @Oli you says `None of these things need to be the same,` it makes it so complex :( . it will be pretty easy by checking is equal ie `Car.objects.filter(Q(make__startswith=curcar.make),
    Q(model__startswith=curcar.model) | Q(seats=curcar.seats)....etc)`

Comment: @Oli, if you can't determine the 5 "closest" by hand, there's no way you're going to be able to do it just with the django ORM. You either need to limit your constraints (same body, same doors, similar price is easy to figure out), or farm out to a decision engine. I would go for a "good enough" query, and build on that until it's time to upgrade to an engine.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton I'm not quite sure what you mean by "by hand". We could go through each car and assign similar matches but that's really time consuming if you're dealing with anything more than a dozen cars. I think I've conquered it anyway. See my answer.

Comment: @Oli what about adding an extra  `manytomanyfield` say `related_items` to `Car` and add manually by admin.

Comment: @Oli gnarly use of `extra`. When I mentioned by hand, I meant for maybe one car by running a number of queries, and then translating that to a solution. I have an unnecessary aversion to using `raw` and `extra` (what if I need to change DB engines?! .. never), but nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
def get_suggestions(model, obj, fields, limit=5):
    """
        `model` django model
        `obj` the model object for which related suggestions needed to be generated
        `fields` lookup fields used in filters
        `limit` maximum number of records return by this function
    """
    suggestions = model.objects.none()
    qs = model.objects.exclude(id=obj.id)

    for field in fields:
        val = getattr(obj, field)
        if val:
            d = {field: val}
            qs_ = qs.filter(**d)
            if qs_:
                suggestions = qs_

    count = suggestions.count()
    if count == 0:
        # pull random records from qs
        suggestions = qs.order_by('?')
        # although using `?` to pick random records is inefficient solution but this is out of scope for this question
    elif count < limit:
        # fill it upto the limit
        suggestions = suggestions | qs.exclude(id__in=suggestions.values_list('id', flat=True)).order_by('?')[:limit-count]

    return suggestions[:limit]

car = Car.objects.get(pk=car_id)    
fields = ['make', 'model', 'body_shape', 'seats', 'doors'] # sort with hightest to lowest precedence

suggestions = get_suggestions(Car, car, fields)
```

Comment: This can be improved as it is just applying filters orderly, missing many other possible combinations of filters, but how many combinations of filters you can afford; is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this can be done at database level. You can add extra columns that show the difference between things and by `ABS`, we're left with a value that is zero-to-infinity where zero is the most similar. A simple but effective similarity ranking!

That's simple for the integers. For the string items, I've had to be more clever.

The make/model is only relevant if both are the same... In which case they are the most important thing. I'm passing through a `CASE` statement to give a binary result. There's probably a cleaner way of doing this but I currently don't know it.

And for the body type... Well that was a bit trickier. I could have just selected the ones where they're the same (as with the make) but instead I've decided to add a new field that describes a body's relative size. A 5 is a bigger car than a 2. Making those distinctions wasn't simple but ranking them now is.

```
car = Car(...)  # my pre-selected car

cars = Car.objects.exclude(pk=car.pk).extra(select={
    "mm_diff": "CASE WHEN make=='%s' AND model=='%s' THEN 1 END" % (car.make, car.model),
    "bodysize_diff": "abs(bodysize-%d)" % car.bodysize,
    "seats_diff": "ABS(seats-%d)" % car.seats,
    "doors_diff": "ABS(doors-%d)" % car.doors,
    "enginecc_diff": "ABS(enginecc-%d)" % car.enginecc,
}).order_by("-mm_diff", "bodysize_diff", "seats_diff", "doors_diff", "enginecc_diff")
```

If you copy this, you should be cautious of SQL injection attacks. My make/models are strictly only alphanumeric (there are several regex/checks while they're being created) so I'm not too worried but if a user is inputting some of the data, make sure everything's escaped.

---

What this isn't good is equally weighting differences. For example, what if I thought the difference in door numbers was *as* important as the difference in engine size? Could we combine and compare differences? But on what scale? Engine size differences are in the hundreds and thousands but seats only range from 2-7...

A problem for another day, perhaps!